# Firebase retrieve returns undefined/object Object

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working on retrieving a child from Firebase with this code:

```
function fetchUserdetails() {
  firebase.database().ref().child('login/').orderByChild('username').equalTo('ivanaldwin').on("value", function(snapshot) {
    document.getElementById('fullname').innerHTML = snapshot.val().username;
    console.log(snapshot.val()); //debug in console
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
        console.log(data.key);
        alert('yep im working dood');
    });
});
}

window.onload = fetchUserdetails();
```

But the code, if i use `snapshot.val().username;` will render `undefined` in the output. but if i use `snapshot.val()` only, the output will be `[Object object]`. Here's my firebase layout:[image: se]

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(snapshot.val());`?

Comment: also `undefined`.

Comment: How about `console.log(typeof snapshot.val());`?

Comment: now `[object Object]` and `object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the username try the following:

```
snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
    let userName = data.val().username;
    console.log(data.key);
    alert('yep Im working dude');
});
```

Your snapshot is at node `login`, therefore after you loop using `forEach` you then can access the child attributes.

Comment: This worked! Can't accept as answer yet though. Didn't know that the child attributes were sort of 'locked' at first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use array index

```
document.getElementById('fullname').innerHTML = snapshot.val()[0].username;
```

But I think you would need the element 0 for that one, which you don't have.
Maybe try

```
document.getElementById('fullname').innerHTML = snapshot.val().child('1').username
```

Comment: Ended up spitting the error `Cannot read property 'username' of undefined`

Comment: the number 1 is a poor name for a node, as you can't reference it as an object child in your code. Either start from 0 so you would get an array where you can use my first line of code, or use names that are letters, where you can reference like snapshot.val().myNode.username